# how to set command line for electron

Tags: command-line, electron

I need a the electron start with transparent window in linux, the documents say I need put --enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu in the command line. Is there a way to pass the command line args in the program not in the  terminal command line.
like this:

```
electron . --enable-transparent-visuals --disable-gpu
```

I need when I run

```
electron .
```

the args have set in the program.It means I just double click the bin file and the args are OK. Don't need to pass them manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them in the main script of the application (main.js), before the 'ready' event of the *app* module is emitted, like so:

```
const electron = require('electron')
// Module to control application life.
const app = electron.app
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-transparent-visuals');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('disable-gpu');

app.on('ready', () => {
  // Your code here
});
```

For a list of other command line switches, you can go [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md)

Comment: It not works very well. Nothing display. My distribution is Linuxmint 18

Comment: I couldn't find any indication that this would behave differently in Linuxmint. Make sure you add the arguments at root level of the main script, just like the `app` constant, and not inside a function or something, and make sure it's before the `ready` event. Also, in case you do some sort of platform check like `if (process.platform !== 'linux') `, please make sure your code is correct. I edited my code to be more like the [electron quick-start example](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js). For more information, please post your code.

Comment: Also, check the css

Comment: This is my code, change from the electron-quick-start.
[electron example](https://github.com/zephyrzoom/test/tree/master/electron)

Comment: On my side it does display 'Hello world!' in black text with transparent background (click the taskbar icon to check). I don't see any css in your code. Keep in mind that if you don't set a background color, the window will be invisible. Have you tried playing around with your css? Maybe something like: `body{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}`

Comment: I just want the transparent background. It displays nothing in my linux. :(

Comment: It may be my OS problem. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Ok, but I seriously doubt this is an OS issue. The text itself is *very* easy to miss, and thus it would seem like it displays nothing. You didn't really answer my previous question: *Did you or did you not try to add a background-color via a .css stylesheet like I suggested*?

Comment: I tried what you told me, and it works. Interesting. I don't know why?

Comment: This is fine. but the alwaysOnTop is not work. while I add `mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` it works.

Comment: Like I said, if no background is set, the window will be completely transparent => 'show nothing'. As for the AlwaysOnTop, that's a separate question and it may be an internal issue, as related issues have been reported before (eg. [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2097) ). Since what I suggested worked, don't forget to mark the answer as 'accepted'. Thank you!