# Electron does not render anything on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, electron

I'm trying to run an electron app (https://github.com/JamieMagee/teams-for-linux to be precise) and while I got it to run and compile, it is now showing whatever was behind the screen - like it is literally never painting the window display.[image]

I know that being based on Chrome, Electron is known to have graphical glitches from time to time but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue - when I jump a few commits back it starts giving a JS exception and does not run at all. Is there a library I need to package or set up to get forms to render on Ubuntu 14.04?

The only warning shown while running:

```
yarn compile v0.15.1
$ rimraf 'app/**/*.js' && tsc 
Done in 2.00s.
~/teams-for-linux/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by ~/teams-for-linux/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)
~/teams-for-linux/node_modules/electron/dist/electron: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by ~/teams-for-linux/node_modules/electron/dist/electron)
```

Comment: These dbus messages look somehow interesting. Could you include them from the terminal in your question? Maybe they're related...

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner See update. Btw the same happened in VS Code today, on a different newer Ubuntu computer. Electron often has very odd graphical glitches - same as Chrome.

Comment: I have the same issue on Linux Mint. The StartWidow of my electron app (index.html) displays, but the JavaScript in renderer.js does not execute. I alo get this no version text. I tried publishing as .deb and AppImage. Works on Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this issue.
This command helped me:

```
yarn electron --disable-gpu
```

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to offer: that you were able to work around the problem by running without GPU acceleration which avoided these window repainting issues.  By why not say that explicitly in your answer?  Just saying something to the effect or "this command line option helped me" is vague (doesn't say how it helped), and exceedingly brief (no details).  I encourage you to write a higher quality answer by explaining yourself more fully.  Browse some of the highest ranked answers on StackOverflow -- they are never this shy on details.

Comment: Another related post with a workaround. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283853/how-to-set-command-line-for-electron